# How to make close button for iAdbannerView

Tags: swift, iad, adbannerview

Can anybody help me in making a close button for iAdbannerview which will pe place above the banner in right topside so that if person do not want to see the ads he/she can tap on close button to hide the ads.Help me in coding Below is the link to open screenshot of my viewcontroller https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z_d4wEKPEFTHVNY1AycVdTNTQ/view?usp=sharing

```
  @IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()




self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
self.adBannerView!.delegate = self
self.adBannerView!.hidden = true //hide until ad loaded

 }

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

  }

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

self.adBannerView?.hidden = false

 }

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

  }

   func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplicationwillLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

return true
}

 func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error:NSError!) {
self.adBannerView!.hidden = true
          }
```

Comment: Well, its not a good idea to implement that ! because no one likes ads anyway. i guess you just don't have to implement ads then  !

Comment: @AaoIi Then you must *pay* for your apps! :)

Comment: @whyceewhite , for sure ! and we can't afford it !

Comment: I would double check with Apple if this is allowable,  some ad services do not allow for items to be placed over ad banners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to do it programmatically :

Create a `UIButton` under `adBannerView`:
`var button = UIButton()`

In `viewDidLoad` instantiate the button and place it at the right top side of the `adBannerView` :

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x + 150, self.view.frame.size.height - 66, 10, 10)
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Yourclosebuttonimagename"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.view.addSubview(button)
button.addTarget(self, action: "hideAd:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

The function will be called `hideAd` :

```
func hideAd(sender:AnyObject){

self.adBannerView.hidden = true
self.button.hidden = true
// or do 
self.button.removeFromSuperview()
self.adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I recommend you remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` because `self.adBannerView!.delegate = self` is enough to run the iAd.

Good luck !